# Nginx server not responding to command line, browser or ftp

Tags: mysql, php, nginx, not-responding

I am having problem with my nginx server. Actually I am running some heavy database and php operations and now it seems that my entire nginx server has stopped responding. I can not access it using terminal (putty) or ftp or browser.

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Is nginx running? Does it accept TCP connections? Do static resources served directly by nginx work? Is there an error message? What do the log files say?

Comment: @mgorven I am a bit novice on this, so here is what I tested. I can ping the ip and it works, but I can not access static files. Also not able to access any log files as I can not access ftp also. I am using FileZilla for ftp. Let me know if I can do anything else to access it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the machine from the network. If that doesn't work, reboot it.

Network traffic is often the source of high load so removing the network connection temporarily will often get an unresponsive server to calm down. Sometimes this can be done remotely by logging into the UI of the switch it is connected to, and logically disabling the port on the switch it connects to.

If it doesn't recover after 5 or 10 min without net access... reboot.